# Change already hosted android app built with java to flutter and update

Tags: android-studio, flutter, google-play

I am New to flutter and i love it. i have an app on the playstore built using java and i want to redo it using flutter so my question is:
Will i be able to rebuild the app and host it on playstore as an updated version of the current android app or will it be a completely different app from the app on the playstore(users wont be able to get the update)?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the app with flutter and update it on the Play Store over your existing Java app. All you need to make sure is

1. Both have same `Package name`.
2. Both have same `Signing Key`.
3. Flutter one has `Version Code` higher than Java one.